# oct2py import successful, any calls to oct2py crashes python

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

I added C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.1\bin to my PATH and can successfully import oct2py, but subsequent calls to oct2py crashes the python kernel.  The kernel crashes in command line python, IPython and Spyder.

Sample code:

```
from oct2py import Oct2Py    # works with no errors
oc = Oct2Py(executable="C:/Octave/Octave-4.0.1/bin/octave-cli.exe")  # also no errors
oc = Oct2Py()  # also returns with no errors.

y = oc.zeros(3,3)   # instantly kills the python
```

I have tried the default Oct2Py factory and tried to initialize it with the executable, but neither seems to work.

The speed to which the kernel blows up feels like a linking error of some sort, but I'm not sure.

Here are my Python and Octave versions:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

---

```
GNU Octave, version 4.0.1
Copyright (C) 2016 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

 Octave was configured for "i686-w64-mingw32".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

octave:1>
```

UPDATE:

I discovered I can push data into Octave (e.g., oc.push('y',5) creates a .mat temp file with the variable y assigned the value of 5), but pulling data (e.g., oc.pull('y')) kills python.